# My function does not always work because of the second argument

Tags: c++, string

My trouble is that my function not always work, and i don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string>
using namespace std;


void fill_zeros(std::string& fill_zeros_str, int fill_zeros_num){
    if (fill_zeros_str.length()<fill_zeros_num){
        int i = 0;

        for (i=0;i<=((int)fill_zeros_num)-((int)fill_zeros_str.length());i++){
            fill_zeros_str = "0"+fill_zeros_str;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    string testString = to_string(2);

    fill_zeros(testString,7);

    cout << testString << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The second argument of fill_zeros (fill_zeros_num) does not work all the time, and I don't know why.

Comment: In what way is the second arg "pesky"? Could you give an example where the function does not behave as expected? The example you provided outputs `00002` which seems to be what you wanted.

Comment: `for (i=0;i<=((int)fill_zeros_num)-((int)fill_zeros_str.length());i++)` looks fishy to me.  Keep in mind that that condition will be re-evaluated at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: How about just coming out and saying what you want it to do and/or what you hope to accomplish/learn by writing this function.

Comment: Does it work? Or does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Because in
`for (i=0;i<=((int)fill_zeros_num)-((int)fill_zeros_str.length());i++)`
the length of `fill_zeros_str`  changes as you add zeros(decrease by one), and you are also adding one to `i`(so, the start is adding by one, and the end is decreasing by one). So the best way is to define a length at the beginning of the function to store the string length.

Comment: This worked, thank you, that was a simple solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is modifying the `std::string` on each iteration, which affects its `length()`.  The loop is re-evaluating the `length()` on each iteration.

You need to calculate the number of zeros wanted and save that value to a local variable first, and then use that variable in your loop.  Also, your loop needs to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Try this:

```cpp
void fill_zeros(std::string& str, size_t min_length){
    if (str.length() < min_length){
        size_t fill_zeros_num = min_length - str.length();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < fill_zeros_num; ++i){
            str = "0" + str;
            // or: str.insert(0, "0");
            // or: str.insert(0, '0');
            // or: str.insert(str.begin(), '0');
        }
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6Ulbp3)

However, there is a much simpler way to implement `fill_zeros()` that doesn't involve using a manual loop at all:

```cpp
void fill_zeros(std::string& str, size_t min_length){
    if (str.length() < min_length){
        str = std::string(min_length - str.length(), '0') + str;
        // or: str.insert(0, std::string(min_length - str.length(), '0'));
        // or: str.insert(str.begin(), std::string(min_length - str.length(), '0'));
        // or: str.insert(0, min_length - str.length(), '0');
        // or: str.insert(str.begin(), min_length - str.length(), '0');
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/jeiWo4)

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

void fill_zeros(std::string& str, size_t min_length){
    if (str.length() < min_length){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::setw(min_length) << std::setfill('0') << str;
        str = oss.str();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/g47FaL)

In which case, you could simply get rid of `fill_zeros()` altogether and apply the I/O manipulators directly to `std::cout` in `main()` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    std::cout << std::setw(7) << std::setfill('0') << 2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/rwtUTw)